# Check the server response code, then export to csv

Tags: python, csv, http-headers, urllib2, server-response

I'm using the below code to check server response codes. Instead of manually entering the URLs, I'd like python to check a CSV (`data.csv`) and then export the results to a new CSV (`new_data.csv`). Does anyone know how to write this?

Thanks for your time!

```
import urllib2
for url in ["http://stackoverflow.com/", "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/"]:
try:
    connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    print connection.getcode()
    connection.close()
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.getcode()

# Prints:
#200 or 404
```

---

UPDATE:

```
import csv

out=open("urls.csv","rb")
data=csv.reader(out)
data=[row for row in data]
out.close()

print data

import urllib2
for url in ["http://stackoverflow.com/", "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/"]:
try:
    connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    print connection.getcode()
    connection.close()
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.getcode()
```

OUTPUT:

```
[['link'], ['link'], ['link'], ['link'], ['link'], ['link']]

200

200
```

---

UPDATE:

```
import csv

with open("urls.csv", 'r') as csvfile:
    urls = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(csvfile)]

import urllib2
for url in urls:
    try:
        connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        print connection.getcode()
        connection.close()
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.getcode()
```

Comment: Try the `csv` module or just use a plain text.

Comment: Thanks, mate. I'm pretty new to the CSV module. I've been able to call the URLs from CSV, however, how do I now ask Python to check the URLs from CSV? Here's what I now have:
`import csv

out=open("urls.csv","rb")
data=csv.reader(out)
data=[row for row in data]
out.close()

print data

import urllib2
for url in ["http://stackoverflow.com/", "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/"]:
    try:
        connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        print connection.getcode()
        connection.close()
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.getcode()`

Comment: You'd better put the code in your question(edit it) so it is clear and more people are possible to see it. @Sam Perry

Comment: You have already got that. Why don't you merge the code. The `data` is already a list containing the urls. By the way, open the csv file in r mode, not rb mode.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @zhangyangyu. I've changed to open with "r". Sorry for my beginner knowledge but i'm struggling to merge the two codes. I thought it would work if I changed to `for url in ["data"]:

@zhangyangyu, would you mind providing the code in an answer?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have your clue from your print data output: [['link'], ['link'], ['link'], ['link'], ['link'], ['link']] - This tells me that you are probably making a mistake with the line data=[row for row in data] as it is giving you a list of lists this is why you can not simply use `for url in data:`.

BTW you will find the whole thing less confusing if you put some thought into naming - e.g. **input** from a file handle called '*out*' and **data** = something based on **data**...

Comment: I've updated the example above. Thanks for your help! I've changed `data=[row for row in data]` and `for url in data:`. However, I now get a large number of errors if Python comes across a 404 responses error: `ile "\script.py"
 connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)`

Comment: If you have a list of URLs that do not point to pages they you will get errors printed for each, if you don't wish to see them then change: *print e.getcode()* to *pass*